# Endeca Web Studio not working

Tags: endeca

When I am in the web studio I click the Search configurations or Dimension Order, I get the following error:

The operation failed because the manager state is 'Stopped'. For the operation to succeed, the manager state must be running. Make sure all ENEs and A-ENEs are running.

It is version 4.8. This was installed and configured long before I got here. I have no experience in Endeca. No idea how it all works and information online isn't very helpful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: Check your available disk space.  Endeca logs weren't capped until version 6.0, so they can get fairly large if you're not keeping tabs on them.

Answer (score 2):

Version 4.8 doesn't have Endeca HTTP Service or Endeca Tool Service, plus it's not clear that the author's installation is running on Windows. I believe Endeca v4.8 only had Web Studio (Tomcat app), JCD, Dgraph, and Agraph processes. having said that the error message indicates that you need to make sure that either Dgraph or Agraph processes are running (ENE is short for endeca navigation engine and is an alias for dgraph, a-ene is an alias for agraph)

There could more information in the tomcat logs, please check those which should be located under workspace\logs folder.

Answer (score 1):

All of the endeca services need to be running. On a windows machine make sure "Endeca HTTP Service", "Endeca JCD", and "Endeca Tools service" are all running.